# Flutter dropdown with scroll controller?

Tags: flutter, dropdownbutton, popupmenubutton, scrollcontroller

Trying to find a dropdown example with scroll controller. What I'm trying to achieve is to load more data when it reach the end of the dropdown, I tried DropdownButton and PopupMenuButton, both no luck as it didn't have a scroll controller parameter. Is there anyway to handle dropdown button in such way that I wanted?

Answer (score 0):

That's because it's not a good practice to load massive data in the drop-down. It's recommended to use a drop-down for specific small-sized data so that users don't have to just scroll infinitely to search for their required option.

You can either navigate the user to another dedicated screen (where there'll be a search let's say) or open a modal bottom sheet.